# How to install "perf" monitoring tool?

Tags: software-installation, monitoring

How do I install the `perf` monitoring tool?

Comment: What exactly do you want to monitor?

Comment: @ddeimeke that seems like an irrelevant question.

Comment: @ddeimeke it doesn't matter

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The `perf` utility can be found in the [linux-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/linux-tools)
 package.

Comment: You also probably want to install [linux-tools-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-tools-generic) since it includes kernel modules that perf interacts with.

Comment: Yep @Allen linux-tools-generic was what I needed!

Comment: Also, if (like me) you have HWE installed, you'll need to install `linux-tools-generic-hwe-$version` (`linux-tools-generic-hwe-20.04` is what I have currently).

Answer (score 144):

On Ubuntu I had to install three packages:

```
apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-`uname -r`
```

Comment: When I tried it, just using
`sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic`
(skipping the part, which depends on the kernel version) was sufficient.

Comment: @Martin-R linux-tools-generic always points at the tools for the most up to date kernel version.  When running an older kernel (e.g. a server with a couple months uptime) if you want perf without rebooting to the newer kernel you have to explicitly install the tools paired with that kernel (hence the `uname -r` shell expansion).

Comment: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-`uname -r`

Comment: ***sudo apt install linux-tools-generic***  on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.5.*
what can be done to run perf on kernel 5.5?

Comment: I too kept getting the "Unable to locate package linux-tools-..." message and nothing helped me fix it until i followed the first part of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082474/1742164) and then came back to this answer and tried it again

Comment: this works for an aws instance also.

Answer (score 40):

Make sure you are installing this tool for the right Kernel release. If you just type:

`sudo apt-get install linux-tools`

It will install it for the latest Linux release in your machine and in case you are booting a previous version (say for stability reason), it will err. In my case it installed for .45 instead of .43 and I had to use the following command to install it:

`sudo apt-get install linux-tools-3.2.0.43`

You can find your Kernel release by typing :
`uname -r`

To make sure it's working right you can try this:
`perf record  /bin/ls`

Answer (score 38):

To get the latest version of perf irrespective of the kernel version (perf version is independent of the kernel version):

```
git clone --depth 1 https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
cd linux/tools/perf
make
cp perf /usr/bin
```

`perf --version` to check the current version

Comment: Build deps for reference `apt-get install build-essential git flex bison`

Comment: This is the right answer if your using a newer kenel. All the answer referring to using dpkg, and apt downloads are dependent on if dpkg repos have access to perf based on your kernel version. Running the latest Ubuntu image 21.04 with a kernel of 5.11, perf does "install" after using dpkg to download, however when trying to run `perf -h` you will be prompted with `WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.11.0-41` (or which ever newer kernel you have that perf is not apart of). Had to literally compile the tool from linux-tools manually.

Comment: that worked to install - but it seems to be installing a different version - it doesn't support `perf trace`

Comment: @stason what is the expected version, what is it installing ?

Comment: it's installing 6.3.x as of this writing. it looks like v6 dropped `trace`, it's there in v5.

I also very much doubt that v6 `perf` would work on kernel 5.x.

may be could add to your answer to suggest to check that the same major version is used as the actual kernel?

Answer (score 11):

## Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-common
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/linux-tools-common

## Debian:

```
sudo apt install linux-perf
```

https://packages.debian.org/buster/linux-perf

Answer (score 8):

In 14.04, the `linux-tools` package does not exist unqualified:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-tools is a virtual package provided by:
  linux-tools-virtual 3.13.0.36.43
  linux-tools-lowlatency 3.13.0.36.43
  linux-tools-generic-lts-trusty 3.13.0.36.43
  linux-tools-generic-lts-saucy 3.13.0.36.43
  linux-tools-generic 3.13.0.36.43
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'linux-tools' has no installation candidate
```

Instead, you can install one of the packages listed, depending upon the kernel you have installed. Most users will want `linux-tools-generic`.

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, this is the correct answer. It will bring in `linux-tools-common` and the specific package for your current kernel version automatically.

Answer (score 5):

On ubuntu "perf" is a shell script that calls a kernel specific perf binary.

But that's not actually needed, perf is compatible. Just remove the wrapper from /usr/bin and copy any of the perf binaries from ./lib/linux-tools* to it.

Comment: that worked - thank you! You could call directly `sudo /usr/lib/linux-tools-5.15.0-67/perf trace date` - try `locate  /lib/linux-tools | grep perf` to find which version you may have.

Answer (score 4):

I installed Linux 3.17.2 on my machine and tried

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-3.17.2
```

it showed that linux-tools is not present.
In this case,
download the required linux kernel version, 
go to linux->tools->perf :

```
cd linux/tools/perf
```

and then run make command :

```
make
```

and then run make install command:

```
make install
```

and then reboot.
You just installed perf manually.

Comment: Reboot is not necessary. Also, if you are to compile from the source code; linux-tools-3.17.2 should not be necessary

Answer (score 3):

Running the following two commands will do it!

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common 
sudo apt-get install linux-tools
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm using 12.04. I get the error perf not found for kernel 3.2.0-60. You may need to install linux-tools-3.2.0-60-generic

Comment: This doesn't look working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it worked for me On Ubuntu 18.04:

After `Command 'perf' not found`, it suggested to install with `sudo apt install linux-tools-common`. Doing so and trying to run `perf` afterward still resulted in:

```
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.15.0-39

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-4.15.0-39-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-4.15.0-39-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generic
```

I decided for `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic` and this was enough.

In case you run into permission-error when trying to use `perf` as non-root, look here:

[Run perf without root-rights](https://superuser.com/questions/980632/run-perf-without-root-rights?newreg=2f81b6d2ba2a4143af62fa81c188aa9a)

Comment: I got the same warning. But then I ran the command you suggested and I still get the same warning.

Comment: linux-tools-oem seems to have been enough.

Comment: @6005 Thx for the feedback, I don't have an idea why you experienced a different behaviour, though.

Comment: This happens because the package your are downloading from the dpkg repo was never compiled for your newer kernel version. So the logic builds a binary that just runs this output. You must do what @bodha suggested. Even after compiling, you need to remove or move these binaries where ever they are based on your path, and replace with the compiled binary you made. You will need to do a lot of `which perf` to find out where they all are.

Answer (score 1):

For debian 9.11 (Stretch)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-perf-4.9
```

https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-perf

You might need to do an

```
apt-get update
```

before.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-virtual
```

Comment: this answer is useless without any hint of the approach targeted