# Cannot find linux-tools-generic for the newest stable kernel linux 11.3

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates, 17.04

I am not able to install `perf` for the latest **linux kernel 11.3 in Ubuntu Zesty(17.04)**. I downloaded the Linux kernel source code for this latest stable release (from `kernel.org`). I then compiled and made all necessary changes. The compilation and builds were all successful and I am now successfully able to boot this kernel. I then have problems installing `perf` for this kernel. The below is the screenshot of the error message :-

```
$ perf
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.11.3

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-4.11.3-4.11.3
    linux-cloud-tools-4.11.3-4.11.3

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-4.11.3
    linux-cloud-tools-4.11.3
akalita@tucher:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-tools-4.11.3-4.11.3
[sudo] password for akalita: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-4.11.3-4.11.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-4.11.3-4.11.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-4.11.3-4.11.3'
```

I am basically not able to find the linux-tools package for this stable kernel version. I have already **updated and upgraded the system and then rebooted it as well.**

I have other kernel images on my system as well (older ones). But I suspect this will be a problem with each of them. What should I do ? How should I approach this problem ?

Comment: There is no `linux kernel 11.3`. You installed an unsupported kernel (4.11.3). Obviously there is nothing for that kernel in Ubuntu repos.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to an unsupported kernel.

Comment: Hi @Pilot6, in https://www.kernel.org, this seems to be the latest stable release.

Comment: Ubuntu does not use kernels from kernel.org. Mainline kernels are not officially supported. You can install them, but do not expect that there will be kernel packages in Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Ok.  Where does Ubuntu use its kernels from ? Where can I find the latest kernels for Ubuntu 17.04 ?

Comment: You do not need to "find" them anywhere. If you update your system, you get the latest Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: to over simplify, Ubuntu, and most distros, start with a kernel from kernel.org, but they typically heavily patch the kernel see https://askubuntu.com/questions/37147/what-are-the-differences-between-the-ubuntu-shipped-kernel-and-the-upstream-kern . For the perf tools on a supported ubuntu kernel see https://askubuntu.com/questions/50145/how-to-install-perf-monitoring-tool.

Comment: For a custom kernel such as a kernel you compiled see https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-compile-a-Linux-perf-tool-with-all-features-For-Linux-4-0-on-Ubuntu . you can not use the ubuntu binaries

Comment: I suggest https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I would leave the question as it is not a kernel driver / compile problem

Comment: Thanks all, I was trying out a certain modification to the kernel sources. This modification is related to perf. So I needed to install linux-tools and perf for the newly modified kernel, which I will compile and build. Then to test my modifications, I would need to use perf. That is why I asked.

Comment: Basically, I will possibly need to compile linux-tools and perf on my own for the custom kernel. Is that correct ?