# How can I resolve this problem : Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.15.0-29-generic

Tags: apt, 18.04

I use this command

```
sudo apt-get install \
linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) \
linux-image-extra-virtual
```

and get this error
Is there anybody can help me to resolve this problem? thanks.

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 Error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`linux-image-generic` should already install the associated `linux-image-extra` package, but the name has been changed to `linux-modules-extra`. Try this to upgrade to the latest kernel:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic
```

Then, reboot and try using the following command instead:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
```

Answer (score 4):

As @mchid said in the comments,

linux-image-extra-*

packages have been renamed

linux-**modules**-extra-*

Comment: Where is this kind of thing documented?

Comment: @bennlich exactly my thoughts, how are we supposed to know this? What is the reason for renaming them, and can't they do some backward compatibility or something?