# trying to get the AX201 wifi card working

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and the wifi doesn't work. I've been trying to solve the problem with the different methods mentioned here, but i guess i don't understand enough to be able to fix is. A lot of the stuff people say i don't fully understand and i just try commands. I hope somebody will have the patience to help me fix this.

I tried the answers on https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/

[Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 is not working on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04)

[Add the lastest intel ax201 wireless firmware work on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404944/add-the-lastest-intel-ax201-wireless-firmware-work-on-ubuntu-20-04/1492845#1492845)

But those didn't work, maybe because i did something wrong. For the second solution i ran into the problem not really knowing if i cloned the right thing, i only did

git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git

sudo cp iwlwifi-*.{ucode,pnvm} /lib/firmware/

For the suggested

sudo apt install linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic

it gave:

```
nina@nina-Aspire-A315-58:~$ sudo apt install linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic
[sudo] password for nina: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic'
E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic'
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic'
nina@nina-Aspire-A315-58:~$
```

I tried
[How can I resolve this problem : Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.15.0-29-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082472/how-can-i-resolve-this-problem-unable-to-locate-package-linux-image-extra-4-15)
but didn't work :(

Some output:  *-network
description: Network controller
product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 14.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
version: 20
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6003204000-6003207fff

uname -r

6.2.0-37-generic

sb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for nina: 
[    2.119839] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.119859] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    2.120298] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.278645] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX101, REV=0x351
[    2.499689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR1 B3, rfid=0x10c000
[    3.514640] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    3.515772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.515783] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[    3.515789] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[    3.515796] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    3.515803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    3.515808] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    3.515813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CC13E | branchlink2
[    3.515818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink1
[    3.515823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink2
[    3.515827] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | data1
[    3.515831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | data2
[    3.515836] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[    3.515840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    3.515845] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00124BBE | tsf low
[    3.515849] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    3.515854] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    3.515858] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0012A748 | time gp2
[    3.515862] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    3.515867] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
[    3.515872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
[    3.515877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
[    3.515882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89001 | board version
[    3.515886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8002FC12 | hcmd
[    3.515891] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    3.515895] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    3.515899] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    3.515904] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    3.515908] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    3.515912] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    3.515917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | wait_event
[    3.515921] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    3.515926] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    3.515930] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    3.515934] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    3.515943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    3.515951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    3.515957] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[    3.516016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.516021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[    3.516027] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[    3.516032] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    3.516037] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455E9C | umac branchlink2
[    3.516041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047257E | umac interruptlink1
[    3.516046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00815B4 | umac interruptlink2
[    3.516051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[    3.516055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00815B4 | umac data2
[    3.516060] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    3.516064] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
[    3.516068] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
[    3.516073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0012A746 | frame pointer
[    3.516077] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887EFC | stack pointer
[    3.516082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[    3.516086] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    3.516117] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    3.516122] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[    3.516145] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005629 | IML/ROM data1
[    3.516173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    3.516197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    3.516217] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    3.516238] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    3.516259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    3.516280] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    3.516301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    3.516323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    3.516344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    3.516364] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    3.516385] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.516408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.516430] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    3.516452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    3.872084] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    3.884400] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[    3.890257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX101, REV=0x351
[    5.022475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    5.023620] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.023623] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[    5.023625] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[    5.023626] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    5.023628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    5.023629] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    5.023630] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CC13E | branchlink2
[    5.023631] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink1
[    5.023632] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink2
[    5.023632] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | data1
[    5.023633] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | data2
[    5.023634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[    5.023635] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    5.023636] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0010B73C | tsf low
[    5.023637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    5.023638] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    5.023639] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00111256 | time gp2
[    5.023639] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    5.023640] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
[    5.023641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
[    5.023642] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
[    5.023643] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C89001 | board version
[    5.023644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8002FC12 | hcmd
[    5.023645] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    5.023646] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    5.023647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    5.023647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    5.023648] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    5.023649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    5.023650] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | wait_event
[    5.023651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    5.023652] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    5.023653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    5.023653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    5.023654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    5.023655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    5.023656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[    5.023694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.023695] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[    5.023696] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[    5.023697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    5.023698] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455E9C | umac branchlink2
[    5.023699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047257E | umac interruptlink1
[    5.023700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081632 | umac interruptlink2
[    5.023701] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[    5.023703] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081632 | umac data2
[    5.023704] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    5.023706] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
[    5.023707] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
[    5.023709] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00111254 | frame pointer
[    5.023710] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887EFC | stack pointer
[    5.023712] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[    5.023714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000004 | isr status reg
[    5.023735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    5.023737] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[    5.023762] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005648 | IML/ROM data1
[    5.023772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    5.023779] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    5.023781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    5.023784] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    5.023787] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    5.023790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    5.023793] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    5.023796] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    5.023798] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    5.023801] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    5.023804] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.023809] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.023831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    5.023836] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    5.378542] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    5.390497] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
[    5.398182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX101, REV=0x351
[    6.746641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    6.747762] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.747769] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[    6.747774] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[    6.747778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    6.747784] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    6.747787] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    6.747791] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CC13E | branchlink2
[    6.747795] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink1
[    6.747798] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C25DE | interruptlink2
[    6.747802] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | data1
[    6.747805] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | data2
[    6.747808] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[    6.747811] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    6.747814] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0010A77C | tsf low
[    6.747818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    6.747821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    6.747824] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00110259 | time gp2
[    6.747827] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    6.747831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
[    6.747834] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
[    6.747838] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
[    6.747841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C89001 | board version
[    6.747844] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8002FC12 | hcmd
[    6.747847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    6.747851] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    6.747854] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    6.747857] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    6.747860] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    6.747863] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    6.747866] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CADF8 | wait_event
[    6.747870] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    6.747873] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    6.747876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    6.747879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    6.747882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    6.747885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    6.747888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[    6.747931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.747934] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[    6.747938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[    6.747942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    6.747945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455E9C | umac branchlink2
[    6.747948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047257E | umac interruptlink1
[    6.747952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081DC8 | umac interruptlink2
[    6.747955] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[    6.747958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081DC8 | umac data2
[    6.747961] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    6.747964] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
[    6.747968] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
[    6.747971] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00110257 | frame pointer
[    6.747974] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887EFC | stack pointer
[    6.747977] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[    6.747980] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000004 | isr status reg
[    6.748004] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    6.748007] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[    6.748031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005646 | IML/ROM data1
[    6.748059] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    6.748082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    6.748102] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    6.748123] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    6.748144] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    6.748165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    6.748186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    6.748207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    6.748228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    6.748250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    6.748271] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.748294] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000501 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.748316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    6.748338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    7.093147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    7.105821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

I really hope one of you will help me. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar errors on a new PC, in terminal do

```
sudo apt install linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I think it doesn't find the stuff i should install, i will  add the outcome in the question above,

Comment: Might need to `sudo apt update` after enabling proposed repos in developer options in Software & Updates

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. I think i'm not supposed to say thanks in the comments, but thank you soooo much!!!

Comment: Click on the checkmark next to my answer to accept it