How can I fix the Wifi problem on Ubuntu 20.04
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Huawei Matebook 14 (Intel Core ultra 5 with arc graphics) because of my project team membership. However, after installing Ubuntu, the Wi-Fi was not working. It is not a connection problem; I simply do not have a button for Wi-Fi on the screen. How can I solve this problem? I have to use the 20.04 version of Ubuntu.

You mention a release, but give no further details. Have you installed a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server? Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop? or other flavor?  What kernel stack are you using (is it the older GA kernel stack? or the newer HWE kernel stack? as newer hardware may benefit from the newer stack).  Default kernel stack is set by install media; but you only provided release details (no clues as to what 20.04 system you installed).  Have you tried any troubleshooter docs?  eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html

Looking at the following link:  https://github.com/zhiiwg/linux-on-matebook-14-2022 suggest the unit is fitted with an Intel AX201. I have seen some posts here regarding that which you might like to search for. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1495421/trying-to-get-the-ax201-wifi-card-working I couldn't find anything on 20.04

It seems to be a quite new computer. Please try 24.04 instead. 20.04 is four and a half years old, and does not have good support for new hardware

Open 'Additional Drivers' and you should see the driver listed. you will see 'do not use the device' AND 'Using (your driver type here)'. Click on 'Using (your driver type here)' and click 'Apply Changes'. If it works, install all updates before restarting your PC. If that doesn't fix it you'll need an ethernet cable that connects directly to the router. At that point you can fix any wifi related issues and install all updates. Good luck.

I have opened the additional drivers and I've just seen "no additional drivers available"

I found this: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/01/14/huawei-matebook-d14-wifi-driver-ubuntu-20-04-installation-guide/   ....It may be of some help. The problem is that you will likely need an internet connection to fix the issue. Setting up a wired-connection with a Cat-5 or higher ethernet cable is the most likely and fastest fix. Here is another link: https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/driver-list/
