# perf-stat does not work for 1ms time interval

Tags: command-line, kernel, performance, monitoring

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and running the `perf stat` command to get some information on various hardware events for an application. I notice on doing `sudo perf stat --interval-print 1`, I get an error saying `print interval must be >= 10ms`. However, in the Ubuntu and Linux manual pages (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html), it mentions that the minimum for `interval-print` is 1ms. By doing `uname -r` I get my kernel version as: 4.15.0-158-generic and I have installed the tool following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/578618/1000263.

Any help on how I can run the `perf stat` command for an interval time of 1 ms on my machine will be really helpful and appreciated. Please let me know if further information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, actually it is [10ms in 18.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/perf-stat.1.html#options) and changed afterward (In or before 20.04).

I checked on on source package of Linux kernel 5.4, [man page of `perf-stat`](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eusd-import-team/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.4/tree/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-stat.txt) mention `1ms`. So you will able to set interval to 1ms if kernel is upgraded to version 5 (like: `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`).